# How to add modules from a custom repository that isn't a package? python

Tags: python, import, module, operating-system, sys

I have tried to use `sys.path.append()` with `os.getcwd()` but it didn't work.

The source was from [**here**](https://github.com/alvations/DLTK) and I've downloaded and extracted them as such:

```
alvas@ubi:~/test$ wget https://github.com/alvations/DLTK/archive/master.zip
alvas@ubi:~/test$ tar xvzf master.zip

alvas@ubi:~/test$ cd DLTK-master/; ls
dltk

alvas@ubi:~/test/DLTK-master$ cd dltk/; ls
tokenize
alvas@ubi:~/test/DLTK-master/dltk$ cd tokenize/; ls
abbrev.lex                         jwordsplitter-3.4.jar  rbtokenize.pl
banana-split-standalone-0.4.0.jar  koehn_senttokenize.pl  splicer.py
igerman98_all.xml                  koehn_wordtokenize.pl  tokenizer.py
__init__.py                        nonbreaking_prefix.de

alvas@ubi:~/test/DLTK-master/dltk/tokenize$ cat __init__.py
from tokenizer import punct_tokenize, rb_tokenize 
from tokenizer import koehn_tokenize, deupunkt_tokenize
from splicer import jwordsplitter, jwordsplitteralvas
```

Those are the functions I want to access from the `~/text/` directory, e.g. the `koehn_tokenize` function. But i can't seem to add the modules/functions into my python interpreter.

```
alvas@ubi:~/test$ wget https://github.com/alvations/DLTK/archive/master.zip
alvas@ubi:~/test$ tar xvzf master.zip
alvas@ubi:~/test$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys, os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/alvas/test'
>>> sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'DLKT-master/dltk'))
['','/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/...', ...,'/home/alvas/test/DLKT-master/dltk']
>>>
>>> import dltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dltk
>>>
>>> from dltk.tokenize import koehn_tokenize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dltk.tokenize
```

**From the python interpreter at `~/test/` directory, how can I access the the `dltk.tokenize` module?**

The functions works if it `cd` into `~/test/DLTK-master/dltk/tokenize`:

```
alvas@ubi:~/test$ cd DLTK-master/dltk/tokenize/
alvas@ubi:~/test/DLTK-master/dltk/tokenize$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __init__ import koehn_tokenize
>>>
```

But I **DO NOT** want to `cd` into the `~/test/DLTK-master/dltk/tokenize` before using the python interpreter. I need to somehow append the module/functions within python.

Comment: Try looking into [```__import__()```](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) and playing with the ```level``` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `master.zip` would contain `dltk/__init__.py`, `dltk/tokenize/__init__.py` then you could try to add it to `sys.path` directly:

```
import sys; sys.path.append('master.zip')
from dltk.tokenize import koehn_tokenize
```

---

> From the python interpreter at `~/test/` directory, how can I access the the `dltk.tokenize` module?

Just add `~/test/DLTK-master` directory to `sys.path`:

```
import sys; sys.path.append('DLTK-master')
from dltk.tokenize import koehn_tokenize
```

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong the module is not dltk, but it's tokenize.

If i understand correctly from your directory tree, dltk it's just a directory with inside another direcotry, you have to import tokenize

Bye